# Mysql Tables into Elastic search

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch

I'm working on search engine in mysql and i have 5 to 6 tables on which i'm applying search technique and i have used fulltext mysql search according to my fulltext search won't work better and faster when data will grow in to millions
I'm looking to apply elastic search on my mysql database for faster rendering of results  . Does it suits that i move all my 5 to 6 tables into one index in elastic search or create separate index of each mysql table in elastic search . which one would be suitable ?? for faster results .

Answer (score 0):

They are two different solution at all. Sql vs NOsql.  Elasticsearch could help you if your searches are on text fields, but depends a lot how you are storing data. If you need to do complex aggregations or generate reports from your data, kibana is not as powerful as other sql friendly tools, so you have to evaluate a lot of things. With low details you provide I'd say that a document-oriented database vs a relational could be better but it's just a guess.

Comment: Well my search is based on mostly on text fields